# Creating an Oauth2 application when an instance of another model is created

Tags: django, django-models, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I'm new with Django and oauth2 provider, I have a model Store , I want to create an Oauth2 application automatically when I create an instance of a store , is that possible ?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this would be helpful for readers : I solved this by making my Store model inherit from oauth2_provider's AbstractApplication
For more details check this :
[Extending the Application model](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#extending-the-application-model)